# Возможные примеры решения с нахождением функции min

Tags: python, min

#### Имеется поток данных о ценах товаров (считайте, что цена всегда больше 0). Необходимо написать алгоритм определения минимального четного числа в этом потоке.

```
sys_stdin = [78, 68, 484, 3, 254, 90, 143, 78, 43, 42, 3053, 473, 5, 8593, 16, 3, 1454, 37, 96, 8547]

x = min([pirce for pirce in sys_stdin if pirce % 2 == 0])
print(x)
```

#### Подскажите какими ещё способами можно решить эту задачу?

#### Пробую решить данным способом

```
sys_stdin = [78, 68, 484, 3, 254, 90, 143, 78, 43, 42, 3053, 473, 5, 8593, 16, 3, 1454, 37, 
96, 8547]
num = [0]
for min_num in  sys_stdin:
    if min_num % 2 == 0:
    print(min_num)
    select = min(min_num)
print(select)
```

, но выдаёт ошибку

```
select = min(min_num)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Вы применяете min к числу, вам интерпретатор это и пишет

Comment: Посмотрите на синтаксис функции `min`

Comment: Вас min(x) не смутил, минимум из чего должна была бы находить такая функция, что с чем сравнивать ? `select = min((select, min_num))` но select надо как то заранее определить и решить вопрос с тем что бы он был изначально либо заведомо больше любого числа, либо например None, но тогда не забыть что для первого элемента min выполнять не надо, а только присвоить его select

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: user500479, если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Ответ, который полностью решил задачу - принять (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можете вот так:

```
sys_stdin = [78, 68, 484, 3, 254, 90, 143, 78, 43, 42, 3053, 473, 5, 8593, 16, 3, 1454, 37,
             96, 8547]
answ = float('inf')
for min_num in sys_stdin:
    if min_num % 2 == 0 and min_num < answ:
        answ = min_num
print(answ)
```

Или вот так:

```
answ_1 = min(map(lambda x: x if x % 2 == 0 else float('inf'), sys_stdin))
print(answ_1)
```

Вывод в обоих случаях:

```
16
```

Answer (score 4):

Вариант с `reduce`:

```py
from functools import reduce

sys_stdin = [78, 68, 484, 3, 254, 90, 143, 78, 43, 42, 3053, 473, 5, 8593, 16, 3, 1454, 37, 96, 8547]

res = reduce(lambda s, x: x if s > x and (x % 2 == 0) else s, sys_stdin)
print(res)
```

или без:

```
sys_stdin = [78, 68, 484, 3, 254, 90, 143, 78, 43, 42, 3053, 473, 5, 8593, 16, 3, 1454, 37, 96, 8547]

res = sys_stdin[0]
for inp in sys_stdin:
    if res > inp and (inp % 2 == 0):
        res = inp
print(res)
```

A можно сделать еще проще и использовать `filter` и `min`:

```py
res = min(filter(lambda x: not (x % 2), sys_stdin))
print(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

Там еще исправления желательны в вашем варианте - дал комментарии ниже:

```
sys_stdin = [78, 68, 484, 3, 254, 90, 143, 78, 43, 42, 3053, 473, 5, 8593, 16, 3, 1454, 37,
96, 8547]
# Зачем этот список?
num = [0]
# Переменная для сравнения - делаем максимальной
select=1000000
for min_num in  sys_stdin:
    # чуть изменили
    if not min_num % 2:
        print(min_num)
        # Исправлено сравнение, вызов min был неверен 
        select = min (min_num, select)
print(select)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# но при n==1 лучше использовать min()
import heapq
min_num = heapq.nsmallest(n=1, iterable=(x for x in sys_stdin if not x % 2))[0]

# такой вариант уже был, но все писали его в более длинном виде
min_num = min(x for x in sys_stdin if not x % 2)
```